# Transactions in Breeze

Tags: transactions, breeze

Is it possible in breeze to execute code within a transaction ? Save the changes only when all the code is successfully executed within it and if something fails in between, rollback the transaction.
I am saving an entity in breeze. If this save is succeeded, I want to save another entity. If there is any error while saving second entity, I want to rollback the save operation of first entity.

```
 var charge = datacontext.createEntity('Charge', chargeEntity);
        return vm.save().then(function () {
                    //save second entity
        });
```

In the above code, if Charge is saved successfully, second entity is saved. But if certain error occurs while saving second entity, is there a way to rollback the previous save ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason to do this, just perform your edits to both entities and save them together using EntityManager.saveChanges(). By default if either save fails, then both will. Also see the answer to this post: [breezejs and entity framework validation after updates, but before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416587/breezejs-and-entity-framework-validation-after-updates-but-before-commit)

Note that is is NOT true for MongoDB backends, because Mongo does not support a concept of transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fire two call,
Most advantage of breeze is bulk operation using one query so
use **savechanges** method.